# Import Dump in mediawiki using importDump.php

Tags: php, mediawiki, wikipedia

I have 127 GB dump file of wikipedia in XML format and trying to import it using using `importDump.php`, I have fresh installtion of mediawiki `1.27.1` on latest version of Xampp.

I am facing the following error after executing

```
php importDump.php < dumpfile.xml
```

Error:

> No handler for model 'wikibase-item' registered in $wgContentHandlers

I found this page addressing this issue https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T85133. But i dont know how to download and merge this patch to my existing installation of mediawiki.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

You're likely missing extensions for WikiBase. (There are several of them.) You can get them from [wikiba.se](http://wikiba.se). However, you'll likely need a lot of other extensions too for importing a Wikipedia dump, so I'm not sure if this is a good idea anyway. (Besides, why?)

Comment: i want to have an offline version of wikipedia on my offline server............what is the purpose of  wikidumps if they cant be imported.??